# How to send news letters in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am trying to send something like news letter Via Zend_Mail but after 12 mail i got this message

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\forga\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php  on line 321

my Code is like:

```
$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$smtpConf = array(
        'auth' => 'login',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => '587',
        'username' =>'xxxxx@xxxxx.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxx'
        );    
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpHost, $smtpConf);

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom("noreply@forga.com", 'Forga');
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    if($html=='on')
        $mail->setBodyHtml($message);
    else
        $mail->setBodyText($message);
    $mail->addto($user);
    $transport->send($mail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the script timeout you get I'd assume your host is slow to send eMails and simply cannot handle bulk sending of eMails. You could increase the time until a script times out with

- [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) — Limits the maximum execution time

A more elegant way would be to send the eMails in separate processes asynchronously. Check out

- *Mysteries of Asynchronous Processing* by [Padraic Brady](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/) Part [1](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/417-The-Mysteries-Of-Asynchronous-Processing-With-PHP-Part-1-Asynchronous-Benefits,-Task-Identification-and-Implementation-Methods.html), [2](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/418-The-Mysteries-Of-Asynchronous-Processing-With-PHP-Part-2-Making-Zend-Framework-Applications-CLI-Accessible.html) and [3](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/419-The-Mysteries-Of-Asynchronous-Processing-With-PHP-Part-3-Implementation-With-Spawned-Child-Processes-Using-Simple-Scripts-Or-Zend-Framework.html).

Part 3 deals with eMails specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer on another posting on parallel processing in PHP [Multithreading/Parallel Processing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678761/multithreading-parallel-processing-in-php/2678928#2678928).  I think it's relevant.  If you need something to be done outside of the individual request it should probably be passed to some kind of queue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you manage the web server yourself?
Up to version 5.3.0, [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) only works in [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode). (deprecated in recent PHP).
You can set [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) in `php.ini`.

See also [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code your sending a single email to each on individually from your server.. Try doing the following.

```
$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$smtpConf = array(
        'auth' => 'login',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => '587',
        'username' =>'xxxxx@xxxxx.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxx'
        );    
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpHost, $smtpConf);
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom("noreply@forga.com", 'Forga');
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$html=='on' ?$mail->setBodyHtml($message) : $mail->setBodyText($message);

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $mail->addto($user);
}

$transport->send($mail);
```

No i might actually be wrong with this because the other email addresses **may** be visible to all recipients, im not sure if that's only the *concerning* section of the email.

Regards