# How to make PHP application working multi-threaded?

Tags: php, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multithreading/Parallel Processing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678761/multithreading-parallel-processing-in-php)

I need to make application which work 10 simultaneously like multi-threading .

Answer (score 0):

If you application is running on the CLI, you can use pcntrl_fork:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php